# HOW TO CHECK DATA RETRIEVED FROM WHICH PARTITION IN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I Have one partitioned table and non clustered Index created on that table, when I am querying on that table it is showing Index seek but performance is not up-to the mark.
         So i decided to see from which partition SQL SERVER is fetching the data,therefore i have look into Estimated And Actual Execution plan but i am unable to see from which partition data gets pulled.

( I meant how to many partition were scanned while fetching data my intention is to check whether sql server is hitting to correct partition or not )

I am not sure whether below images will appear in my post or not because i have less reputation, Please Excuse me from that.

[Execution Plan for my Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RovF2.jpg)

[image]

[Actual Execution Plan of Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvOPu.jpg)

[image]

Comment: There can be rows read from every partition, right? Instead this, could you show the actual query - there could be something that can be optimized?

Comment: Dear @Yogesh Sharma                                                                     
select transactiondate,mobileno,status,b.operator,b.circle from  a with (index (IX_MV))
left join b on left(right(mobileno,10),5)=b.phoneseries
where transactiondate>='24-nov-2017' and transactiondate<'25-nov-2017' and 
Id in (select ID from c where DEPLOYMENTID='1511516069340006931'
and recordtype='103')

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5156185/6305294

Comment: Fix your keyboard - the **CAPS LOCK** key seems to be **STUCK**.....

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `$PARTITION` function (documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/partition-transact-sql)) to get where you're going. In essence, you call it along with your partition function and the arguments to that partition function and it will return a partition number.

For example, let's say I had an Orders table that was partitioned by month on date_created using a partition function called PF_Orders__date_created I could write the following query to get a histogram of rows in the data set by partition:

```
select $PARTITION.PF_Orders__date_created(date_created),
   count(*)
from dbo.Orders
group by $PARTITION.PF_Orders__date_created(date_created)
order by $PARTITION.PF_Orders__date_created(date_created);
```